# count the number of 1st and 0's with a specific date

Tags: c#, sql

In my database i have column name department and employed(return type is bit - 0 or 1), i would like to count the number of employee employed in each department (there are 5 departments) for this year and rank the department who has the highest employee. I need help combining SQL query.

This is how i can calculate 0'1 and 1's `SELECT COUNT(CASE Authorised WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) FROM TableName;`
and this is how i can select date for this year: `

```
SELECT distinct * 
From TableName 
WHERE Time BETWEEN CONVERT(Date,@Time) AND CONVERT(Date, @Time2)
```

How do i combine these query?

Comment: What are you trying to solve. That is why is there need for date and why do you need ones and zero?? This looks like a sql query using grouped by Department and count employed.

Comment: Employee column have return type as bit so i would like to count the numbers of 1's which are the employee employed at a company X. The query should only calculate number of 1's for this year.

Comment: If you need to count 1's in a result where 0 and 1 are valid, you can simply SUM instead of COUNT. However be careful of nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this query, the query returns all departments name and the total of employees in it.

```
   SELECT 
        DEPARTMENTNAME, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
    FROM 
        TABLENAME 
    WHERE 
        TIME BETWEEN 
           CONVERT(Date,@Time) 
        AND 
           CONVERT(Date, @Time2)
    GROUP BY DEPARTMENTNAME
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Grate, this is what i needed. But in total column how do i make highest number appear on top of the list. And i am returning the list via `data` if i want to display this info to web-browser how do i write my [webmethod]? that then can be called through ajax

Comment: I know nothing about `webmethods`. To the highest number appear on the top, you need to create a subquery , I editted my answer.

Comment: i get error  `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.` `Incorrect syntax near '}'.`

Comment: whats db are u using?

Comment: i am using 2008, updated answer shows lows to highest. I want highest to lows.

Comment: I changed my query. You need to specify its in your question not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how your sql should be.

```
declare @WhatEverYourTableNameIs Table
(
Department varchar(3),
employed bit,
employeddate date
)

Insert into @WhatEverYourTableNameIs
Values
('dem',1,'2014-1-1'),
('dem',1,'2014-2-1'),
('dem',0,'2014-2-1'),
('eem',1,'2013-2-1'),
('dem',1,'2013-2-1'),
('eem',1,'2014-2-1')

Select Department, Count(employed) AS Cnt
From @WhatEverYourTableNameIs
Where employeddate >'2013-12-31' and employed = 1
Group by Department
order by Cnt desc
```